# How do perform an nginx rewrite for endpoint rewrite

Tags: regex, nginx

How do I write an nginx rewrite to do the following:

https://anydomain.com/v1/article -> https://anydomain.com/v1/index.cfm/?endpoint=/article

Here "anydomain.com/v1/" could be any value.

Also if I may be permitted to add another one:

https://anydomain.com/services -> https://anydomain.com/?id=services

.. where by "https://anydomain.com" could be any thing, so could be:

tomatoes.com/plants -> tomatoes.com/?id=plants

Really struggling with regex so any help much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 1):

We can possibly start with an expression such as:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?anydomain\.com\/v1\/)(.+)
```

for first part of the problem.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/FmhPzs/1/)

For the second one, we can start with:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?anydomain\.com\/)(services)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/5GTJQ5/1/)

If domain could be anything, we would simplify it to:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?.+\.com\/)(services)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/EDUNjc/1/)

Or:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?.+\.com\/v1\/)(.+)
```

#### [Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/H6Ed31/1/)

and we continue to figure out suitable expressions that would fulfill our desired goals/outputs.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]